# React Page crashing when non-existing [2] array item doesnt exist - ternary display for if does not exist failing

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

So this feels like a very rookie error.
I have connected to a free online api that returns current sports events and their odds.
Im keeping it simple and just taking the first lot of odds from the first bookie in the array returned.
I then want to return a list with the Home_team Win/Lose/Draw odds and the away_team Win/Lose/Draw.

Easy enough to get to the odds with the code below. However when i add in the 'Draw' options it goes wrong and crashes. You see not every event has a draw option you can bet on. So i wanted just a nice simple 'N/a' for any results.
I have been trying to whittle it down and give the code the only display if their is a 3rd [2] asset in the array of outcomes.

```
    {match.bookmakers[0].markets[0].outcomes.find((outcome) => outcome.name === match[2]).price}
```

This goes in the p tag with 'Na x' in it. is where the line of code with the result is supposed to go. This is what i thought would work. If i add it normally the code crashest but i thought the ternery outcome would prevent it.

Here is the excerpt that covers all you need to know. I have no state appart from allFoundOdds

```
<section className='grid gap-1 overflow-y-scroll max-h-[320px] w-full'>
   {allFoundOdds.length &&
       allFoundOdds.map((match, index) => {
           console.log('item found', match);
             return (
               <article
                  key={index}
                  className='bg-green-100 border-b-2 border-solid border-black'
                >
                 <div className=''>
                   console.log(
                    match.bookmakers[0].markets[0].outcomes.find((outcome) => 
                     outcome.name === match.home_team).price
                      )}
                    <section className='flex justify-between'>
                      <div className='overflow-hidden'>
                        {match.home_team}{' '}
                      </div>
                      <div>
                         WIN{' '}
                          {
                           match.bookmakers[0].markets[0].outcomes.find(
                              (outcome) => outcome.name === match.home_team
                            ).price
                          }
                        </div>
                        <div>
                          LOSE{' '}
                          {
                            match.bookmakers[0].markets[0].outcomes.find(
                              (outcome) => outcome.name === match.away_team
                            ).price
                          }
                        </div>
                        <div>
                          DRAW{' '}
                          {match.bookmakers[0].markets[0].outcomes.find(
                            (outcome) => outcome.name === match[2]
                          ) ? (
                            <p>Na</p>
                          ) : (
                            <p>Na x</p>
                          )}
                        </div>
                      </section>
                      <section>{match.away_team}</section>
                    </div>
                  </article>
                );
              })}
          </section>
```

I tried varying the outcomes, search team and index

Comment: Can you provide the error logged in the console?

Comment: the idea is good but you still can't find an item that does not exist. The right approach is to check the array length. `if (array.length < 3) then...` before and run that function only if it is false.